# How to Register an App to Open a Location

Tags: ios, mapkit

We have an automotive app which we would like to open on location share - i.e. when a user tries to share a location inside Maps, a list of capable apps, such as Messenger, Viber, Mail etc. shows up.

We have added capabilities, but we only show under "Routing Apps". We also need to appear in the "open/share with" app list.

Our current settings:

Maps - enabled (Cars),

In the info.plist file:

```
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MKDirectionsRequest</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.maps.directionsrequest</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Since Apple does not use the "maps" URL scheme, simply registering for that scheme will not work.

Any idea what we are missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the extension the

```
NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount
```

key and set this bool to `true`. iOS handles locations as web urls, so this should help you out.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/SystemExtensionKeys.html)

Comment: Thanks! I should also add that creating a new extension target in Xcode does all that for you.